# Why is so big difference in variant of change excel value?

Tags: vba

Please explain me, why the second variant is more faster?

```
iTimer! = Timer
sname = Split(Cells(2, 300).Address, "$")(1)

Range("A300:" & sname & "600").Value2 = Range("A300:" & sname & "600").Value2

    MsgBox "Time is " & _
Timer - iTimer! & " sec.", vbExclamation, ""
```

Executes in ~ 1 sec

```
iTimer! = Timer
sname = Split(Cells(2, 300).Address, "$")(1)
Range("A1:" & sname & "300").Select
Range("A300:" & sname & "600").Value2 = ActiveCell.Value2

    MsgBox "Time is " & _
Timer - iTimer! & " sec.", vbExclamation, ""
```

Executes in  ~ 0.01 sec

Answer (score 1):

For me the 1st variant, i.e. without the `Select-ActiveCell` shenanigan, is faster (by about 6-8 times) than the second variant (with `Select-ActiveCell`).

That is to be expected, because each communication between VBA and the Excel sheet has a certain overhead to it, and you're minimizing the number of interactions in the first variant.

Now I have no idea why you would experience the reverse. Unless it's a typo and you meant variant 1 is faster? I don't know. Note that I tested it on Excel 2003 (and therfore had to reduce the number of columns to 256 in the test, i.e. `Cells(2, 256)`). I don't see why results would be different in Excel 2007 or 2010, but unfortunately I don't have those and can't test them.

Also, I used `Debug.Print` instead of `MsgBox` to display the results, which is much less annoying when doing multiple realizations of the test.